# Is there a term of art for the collection of non-gameplay screens or pages

Tags: terminology, menu, screen-management

Is there a term of art for the collection of non-gameplay screens or pages in a game. I am thinking of screens such as:

- title screen
- options menu (key bindings, volume, graphics quality)
- credits screen
- hi-score table (maybe extradiegetic?)
- help page
- etc

These are all 'meta-screens', in that they help the player manage the gameplay experience, but are outside the gameplay space.

The term I am looking for should  not include screens for extradiegetic elements, such as inventory management, character dialog boxes, hint screens etc. as these are all related to, or control gameplay state.

Answer (score 1):

Not really (or at least if there is a technical term I've never heard it in common use, but maybe somebody who wanders in from the UX StackExchange site can educate me).

I've heard them informally referred to with a variety of terms, primarily:

- non-gameplay screens
- shell or shell screens
- menu screens